# Homework Write a test program that prompts the user to enter an integer and reports whether the integer is a palindrome

Tags: java, netbeans

**Objective:**
(Palindrome integer) Write the methods with the following headers:

// Return the reversal of an integer, i.e., reverse(456) returns 654
public static int reverse(int number)

// Return true if number is a palindrome
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)

Use the reverse method to implement isPalindrome. A number is a palindrome
if its reversal is the same as itself. Write a test program that prompts the
user to enter an integer and reports whether the integer is a palindrome.

**My code is below... My attempt is below. I've collapsed and I don't know what else to do BUT come here. I'm stuck on the Boolean portion of the code and do not know if the rest of this code is right. I've scoured the internet and seen very few examples but none of them made any sense. I'm a visual learner, so none of this really makes sense to me. Started Java 2 months ago so please don't expect me to produce gold with extremely limited knowledge. I need help-help, not petty or witty comments. If you don't want to offer help, don't comment.**

```
public class NewClass {

public static int reverse(int number) {

int remainder = 0;

while (number != 0) {

  remainder = number % 10;
  number = number / 10; 
  System.out.print(remainder);
 }

   System.out.println(" is the reverse number.");
   return remainder;
 }
    //I don't really know what to do here.
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number, int remainder) {
    return number == remainder;
    }
   //Nor do I know what I'm doing here. I'm supposed to make the result from 'reverse' either true or false but I don't know what it write, considering the 'Boolean' portion is unfinished.
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
   java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
   int number = input.nextInt();

   reverse(number);
   int remainder = 0;

   if ( remainder == ture)
  }
}
```

**Revised:**

```
    public class NewClass {

    public static int reverse(int number) {

    int reverse = 0;

    while (number != 0) {

      reverse = (reverse * 10) + number % 10;
      number = number / 10; 
     System.out.print(reverse);
   }

    System.out.println(" is the reverse number.");
    return (reverse);
  }

     public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        return (number == reverse(number)); //Still being asked to introduce this line. I don't know what that means. My book says nothing and the internets isn't helping.
 }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int number = input.nextInt();

    reverse(number);

        if (number == reverse(number)) {
             System.out.println(number + " is a palindrome");
       }
        else{
            System.out.println(number + " is not a palindrome");        
        }
    }
 }
```

**Results: 
run:

```
Enter an integer: 121
112121 is the reverse number.
112121 is the reverse number.
121 is a palindrome
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)**
```

My question: I don't know what I'm doing with the true and false portion of this code. The point is to check the number, compare it to the reversed number checking whether it is a palindrome or not. The second issue is with the reverse number repeating itself with double the number... I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

**Query:**

```
   public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
            return (number == reverse(number));
          }
```

I'm being asked to introduce this line but I don't know what it means. It's the only error I have. It's supposed to return the true or false, correct? What do I do with it because it seems like I created a code that doesn't need that specific line, even though it is required.

Comment: What is the max size of the number? Are there any memory constraints?

Comment: I don't think so. The instructions above is all that was given. Just as long as '12321' is returned true or any mirror image.

Comment: Chris, re the revision and duplicate output, stop printing things in `reverse`. _All_ it should do is return the reversed number. If you want to print it, do that in `main`: `System.out.println ("Reversing " + number + " gives " + reverse(number));`. As to the true/false bits, if the number reversed is the same as the number you print "it's a palindrome", else you print "no, it's not". I'm not sure how I could make that any clearer.

Comment: Uhh... I think I'm still having some trouble understanding this. I've cleared up the duplicate entries but `return (number == reverse(number));` remains to be remedied. I still don't understand what "introduce" means and it's the only thing stopping me from turning this program in...

Comment: As per your other question asked on this site, the "introduced" problem appears to be because you're duplicating `isPalindrome` within `main`, by comparing `number` against `reverse(number)`. Hence you're never actually calling that function. In `main`, you should just have `if (isPalindrome(number)) ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! You have been the greatest amount of help! I'm a struggling visual learner trying my best to learn the "other way". That's why I prefer not to see any answers, but extensive explanations go a long way for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about how to implement `isPalindrome` in terms of `reverse`, it's simply figuring out if the number and its reverse are the same.

So, for example, `767` is a palindrome because, when reversed, it's equal to the original. However, `314159` is *not* a palindrome because its reversal is a totally different number, `951413`.

That means pseudo-code like this should suffice (I've included `reverse` because your current implementation, while close, returns the final remainder rather than the reversed number):

```
def reverse(num):
    rnum = 0
    while num != 0:
        rnum = (rnum * 10) + (num % 10)
        num = num / 10
    return rnum

def isPalindrome(num):
    return (num == reverse(num))
```

---

If you want to nut it out yourself, don't look below. This is how I'd approach it for this level of skill and I'm providing it just for completeness.

```
public class Test {
    public static int reverse (int num) {
        int rnum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            rnum = (rnum * 10) + (num % 10);
            num = num / 10;
        }
        return rnum;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome (int num) {
        return (num == reverse (num));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome (767));       
        System.out.println(isPalindrome (12321));       
        System.out.println(isPalindrome (4));       
        System.out.println(isPalindrome (314159));       
    }
}
```

Comment: 'def'? I don't think I'm that far into the book.

Comment: @ChrisRedfieldea That is not java. It is explanation code ie pseudo-code

Comment: '(rnum * 10)' doesn't this just become 0?

Comment: Yes but it changes because the num % 10 will not return 0

Comment: Really hate to ask this question: Do I update my previous post with my... updates? I'd like to do this correctly.

Comment: @Chris, generally not, unless there's more information requested for the _specific_ problem. Since the specific question is about implementing `isPalindrome`, I think that's answered. If, after you've converted my pseudo-code to Java, you _still_ have problems, ask another question.

Comment: I converted the code but I'm being asked by `NetBeans` to introduce `return (number == reverse(number));`  I have't the slightest idea of what that means.

Comment: @Chris, it depends on whether you want _help_ or the _answer?_  If the latter, I can give you the correct code but that won't make you a better programmer as quickly as if you fix it yourself. Never mind, I'll put the code there, you can use it or not use it as you see fit.

Comment: Nah, don't want the answer just... an explanation. I don't understand what I'm introducing.

Comment: @Chris, I'd compare what you've written with what I provided as a Java solution and, hopefully, the problem will become obvious. Otherwise, post a new question with your changed code (referring back to this one as a link) detailing what the new problem is.

Comment: I'm trying my hardest to work this out right now, I just need time, and for people not to disappear. I desperately need the help!!!

Comment: @Chris, nobody is disappearing. Well, individuals may disappear but the SO swarm will keep working. I'm trying to help you out by, for example, getting you to post a new question for a new problem, where thousands of eyes will look at it, rather than attempting to carry on a conversation in comment boxes where it'll be seen by me and maybe five other people tops.

Comment: @Chris, edits are fine provided you don't change the very nature of the question (hence rendering all answers to date as useless). You've taken the right approach, adding you edits as an addendum, without changing the actual question itself. That will work a couple of times but you should still keep in mind the guideline: if the stuff you want to add is really a different question, ask a new question. More than a couple of addenda will likely change the question beyond recognition :-)

Comment: That has been confusing me as well. I never knew whether to use the edit function or to use  "Answer my Question".

Answer (score -1):

I personally use my two methods for doing it, but the guy who did the StringBuilder thing did good too :).
Here is my code for reversal and then I call that and check if it a palindrome.

```
public static String reverseString(String str)
{
    String blank = "";
    for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        blank = blank + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return blank;
}
// NOW you can call isPalindrome("Whatever string you wanna check.");
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str)
{
    String reverse = reverseString(str);
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate to say it but now I'm just confused as to why String is required, and the  'for' statement.

Comment: @Chris, you don't need strings, in fact you _shouldn't_ use them. The assignment text you posted clearly specs the functions as taking `int` types.

Comment: Sorry, I was just suggesting what you could do if you wanted to use a reverse method for a palindrome. I was thinking you could convert the int to a string then find if it was a palindrome and convert it back if you ever needed. This was solely for reference since you asked for a way to finish your project.

Answer (score -1):

Here is example for check the given number is palindrome or not .

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter a number : ");
    int palindrome = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    if(isPalindrome(palindrome)){
        System.out.println("Number : " + palindrome + " is a palindrome");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Number : " + palindrome + " is not a palindrome");
    }       

}

/*
 * Java method to check if number is palindrome or not
 */
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int palindrome = number; // copied number into variable
    int reverse = 0;

    while (palindrome != 0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
    }

    // if original and reverse of number is equal means
    // number is palindrome in Java
    if (number == reverse) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Okay. This is just as confusing as the I'm supposed to have both `public static int reverse(int number)` and `public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)` in my code and this looks like a backwards version of what I had posted. Thank you for the code but I don't understand the re-workings of yours.